# How to load a custom Block

Tags: extensions, blocks

I just started at developing extensions for Magento and trying to create a simple module that alert when the main page load.

So I created an extension in app/code/local/namespace/mymodule and  PopupBlock.php file in block folder:

```
<?php die("1"); 
    class Michael_Popup_Block extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
        die("1");
        protected function _construct()
        {
            die("1");
            parent::_construct();
        }
    }
?>
```

Also, in my etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Michael_Popup>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Michael_Popup>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <popup>
                <class>Michael_Popup_Block</class>                
            </popup>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <popup>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Michael_Popup</module>
                    <frontName>popup</frontName>
                </args>
            </popup>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Why my block didn't load? how tell magento to load my block?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class name you give for blocks looks incorrect. Going by your file system path, it looks like your class needs to be defined as:

**Michael_Popup_Block**

Then when you are trying to load the block, it would be done as 'popup/popup'

The class name given for the actual class should reflect this as: 
**Michael_Popup_Block_Popup** and be saved in the Blocks/Popup.php file.

Comment: Then when you are trying to load the block, it would be done as 'popup/popup'" do you mean in layout files? I want that my block load automatically... in any magento page... Do you understand what I mean? BTW: I edit my Question according your answer... thanks.

Comment: Yes the block type would become that in layout files. As to loading automatically on any page, you'll need to ensure you put it into a layout point that will be loaded across all pages. Likely under <default>

Comment: but I want to create an extension that not need to add any line in template file for install it. I create this extension for non-programmers guys. how it should work? maybe I'm mistake in my approach..

Comment: In your extension you should declare an layout update file which will enable you to add the block to layout handles as needed.

Comment: in layout.xml should be in design directory right? in default package in default theme...?